# Describe a type for instance of template param

Tags: typescript, interface, inversion-of-control

I am trying to implement a simple ioc-container with type-checking.

I want to pass the "register" method a abstract class type and the instance of some derrived type.

And in "resolve" I want to pass an abstract class type and return typed instance, witch I have passed in "register method".

How should I decribe the type of "instance" param in "register" function? I was able to achieve correct type checking for "resolve" method, but this technic with "{prototype: T}" dosn't work with "register" method.

```
const _items = new Map();

export class IoC {
    public static register<K>(service: K, instance: any) {
        _items.set(service, instance);
    }
    public static resolve<T>(service: {prototype: T}): T {
        return _items.get(service);
    }
}

// usage
IoC.register(AppServer, new TestAppServer());
IoC.resolve(AppServer)
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: This seems to work fine : `public static register<T>(service: { prototype: T }, instance: T) {
        _items.set(service, instance);
    }`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir oh, thanks) yeh, it looks like this should work - i will try it. But also its looks like a hack for me. I mean using {prototype: T}. Is there any other options?

Comment: You can also use a constructor signature in some cases `new (...a:any[]) => T`. But I think you want to use abstract classes as well so the prototype solution is the only one that will work with those

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with this.

```
const _items = new Map();

export class IoC {
    public static register<T>(service: {prototype: T}, instance: T) {
        _items.set(service, instance);
    }
    public static resolve<T>(service: {prototype: T}): T {
        return _items.get(service);
    }
}
```